# How to convert image to matrix form in QtCreator?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qtgui

I can displayed an image with Qt in a gui application.I want to obtain numeric(matrix) form of image, because I studied on image processing, but I cannot convert the displayed image to matrix form. I do not know what code is used. Can anyone help me with this?
Code of displayed image is given below;

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow
{
ui->setupUi(this);
QPixmap pix("/home/zeynep/Masaüstü/right.jpg");
QRegion exposed;
pix.scroll(-90,100,pix.rect(), &exposed);
ui->label_pic->setPixmap(pix);
}
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
delete ui;
}
```

Comment: Can you rephrase the question?

Comment: Please provide more details about the steps that you took, what was the result and what were you expecting.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to access pixel data in numeric form. You should use `QImage` instead of `QPixmap`. You can use `size()` to access image's size, `pixel()` to obtain `QRgb` value of a pixel, and `qRed`, `qGreen`, `qBlue` and `qAlpha` global functions to split `QRgb` value to color components. This should be enough to convert pixel data to matrix that can be stored in `QVector< QVector<int> >`.